# Arduino UTFT Touch align RIGHT with margin

Tags: tft, print

I am using a TFT Touch screen on an Arduino Mega, with UTFT and UTouch libraries.
When I use the code below, the text is aligning to right, all the way to the edge of the screen. Is it possible to give it a margin?

```
tft.print("Text", RIGHT,12)
```

Thank you,
Andi

Comment: `tft.print("Text ", RIGHT,12)`

Comment: That's interesting workaround. I realise now that I didn't think my question through, because I will also need it with integers. Is there a similar workaround I can do with those?